# ¿Cómo soluciono este error en AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android-studio, aplicación-movil, android-manifest

Desde que actualice el *Android Studio* tengo un problema con el archivo AndroidManifest.xml.

> ```
> A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').
> File 'E:\AndroidStudio\IntentsImplicitos\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.
> ```

¿Alguien sabría una solución?

Answer (score 0):

El problema se presenta en los archivos generados ya que se encuentra en el directorio `\app\build\`. Si tu proyecto funcionaba sin problema y lo que realizaste fue una actualización de Android Studio, en este caso Invalida el cache y reinicia Android Studio, eso debe ser suficiente.

Realizalo desde el menú

`File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias

Comment: Recuerda marcar como solución la respuesta que ayude a resolver la problematica expuesta en la pregunta, revisa [tour], saludos.